# Storage Use Case "Logging + Images + Metadata"

Tags: database, logs, document-management, sql-server, log-analysis

I have the following use case for which I'm trying to find an optimal use of either filsystem, database (rdbms or a flavour of noSql solution). Any advice is welcome, as I want to see what is optimal.

1. **Client application**: will generate logs intervals of 1-3 seconds. By logs I mean structured log data (either about connections, applications used, processes used, screenshots, etc..). Some log data will be structured, some will be unstructured (where the schema can change thus).
2. **Storage solution**: will need to persist all this data very fast. Will sit on 1-* server(s). It doesn't matter if it's a hybrid solution between filesystem/rdbms/(any suitable flavour of) noSql.
3. **Post processing**: the data needs to be queryable ofcourse. E.g. just a key-value store would not suffice, that's a given (maybe for the screenshots only yes).

As a reference, here's a more concrete example:

1. User runs the client for 2-3 hours (during a "monitoring period"). It sends log data over the wire to the server (storage). **Writing speed** and **data accuracy** is vital here.
2. Management system accumulates the data and makes a report on certain characteristics. All log data should be able to be fetched if needed - but there will be a specific query for a set of users in a given monitoring period. **Reading speed** is less necessary here, but **data accuracy** and finding all log parts back eventually is necessary.

If I need to give more information, please let me know.